# Cannot connect to database using TOAD?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, toad

I get a error while trying to connect using TOAD:

```
ora 12154 tns could not resolve the connect identifier specified(myDBname)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be mis-naming the server...

If you are using local naming (TNSNAMES.ORA file):
Make sure that "TNSNAMES" is listed as one of the values of the NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH parameter in the Oracle Net profile (SQLNET.ORA)
Verify that a TNSNAMES.ORA file exists and is in the proper directory and is accessible.
Check that the net service name used as the connect identifier exists in the TNSNAMES.ORA file.
Make sure there are no syntax errors anywhere in the TNSNAMES.ORA file. Look for unmatched parentheses or stray characters. Errors in a TNSNAMES.ORA file may make it unusable.

Try using the IP(rather then the name) of the Oracle serverin tnsnames.ora, and check you have permissions.  Can you ping the server?